# wifi hotspot client list does not list all wifi clients

Tags: wifi-hotspot, wifi-tethering

I have an embedded device that I am connecting to a Samsung GS3 hotspot. It connects fine, but does not show up in the "Connected devices" list. It does show up in /data/misc/dhcp/dnsmasq.leases.

Can anybody point me to the right section of android code that creates and displays the "Connected devices" list? I want to modify the DHCP client in my embedded device so that it shows up in the list properly (it's the easiest way to get the assigned IP address). Do I need to change more than just the DHCP client?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out my problem. I am using an ethernet-wifi bridge module, which means the wifi client mac does not match the dhcp client hwaddress. This is why it does not show up in the client list.

I have a static IP address assigned to the bridge, and when I use the wifi mac in my dhcp requests (and set the broadcast flag), then the IP address assigned to my embedded board shows up in the android client list.